# how to call a route of node server from android app

Tags: android, node.js

> ```
> I am working on android for the first time, I just want to connect my android app with node server on a button click. my node server is
> ```
>
> running on localhost and my mobile is also connected to the same
>   network. can it be possible to connect my android app with running
>   node server. what i have to do to call a route of server that only
>   prints "Hello world" in console.log of server.
>           If possible please help me with the code.
>           Thanks.

```
**This is my ooClick function in android.**
public void sendMessage(View view) {

         name     =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
         email      =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
         phone       =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
         address       =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);


         try {
             String nme    = URLEncoder.encode(name.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
             String eMail  = URLEncoder.encode(email.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
             String ph   = URLEncoder.encode(phone.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
            String add    = URLEncoder.encode(address.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");



            // Create http client object to send request to server
            HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Create URL string

            String URL = "http://192.168.0.183:3000/save?text1="+nme+"&text2="+eMail+"&text3="+ph+"&text4="+add;
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please wait, connecting to server."+URL,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try
            {
                          String SetServerString = "";

                        // Create Request to server and get response

                          HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                         ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                         SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

                          // Show response on activity 

                         //content.setText(SetServerString);
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"response"+SetServerString,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
           catch(Exception ex)
              {
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


**This is my function in node server**


app.get('/save', function(req, res){

        var text1= req.param('text1');
        var text2= req.param('text2');
        var text3= req.param('text3');
        var text4= req.param('text4');
console.log(text1+' '+text2+' '+text3);

});
```

**I just want to print the texts in console.**

Comment: You need the ip address or url of the server, something other than "localhost".

Comment: ya i am providing the url ip address but still in dont prints any thing on console. i can able to access the page from the browser.

Comment: what console? what code are you using?

Comment: I have given the code that i was using in java as well as in node server. can you able to help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the Retrofit library. This makes it very easy to make HTTP calls from and Android app. Also, you will need the external IP address or server name in order to access the data over your network. "localhost" always refers to the current machine where the software is running. For your desktop, "localhost" is the desktop; for your Android device, "localhost" is the Android device.